# How to Hide Blank Line in HTML Pre Tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am working on Form Generator and I want conditionally show attributes in code syntax. For that, I am using `<pre>` tag.

I am conditionally displaying attributes and I want to show nothing if there is nothing (null) but pre tag is rendering a blank line instead.

I am using Vue template style

My Code

```
<pre class="CodeBackground">&lt;template&gt;
    &lt;v-form ref=&quot;Form&quot;&gt; 
        &lt;v-container class=&quot;text-center&quot;&gt;<span v-for="(Field, index) in Fields" :key="index">
            {{Field.Type === 'TextField' ? "&lt;v-text-field " : ''}}
                {{FormSettings.Dense === true ? 'dense' : null}}
                {{FormSettings.InputStyle === 'Filled' ? 'filled' : null}}{{FormSettings.InputStyle === 'Solo' ? 'solo' : null}}{{FormSettings.InputStyle === 'Outlined' ? 'outlined' : null}}</span>
        &lt;/v-container&gt;
    &lt;/v-form&gt;
&lt;/template&gt;</pre>
```

Output (If no condition is false):

```
<template>
    <v-form ref="Form"> 
        <v-container class="text-center">
            <v-text-field 


        </v-container>
    </v-form>
</template>
```

Expected Output:

```
<template>
    <v-form ref="Form"> 
        <v-container class="text-center">
            <v-text-field      
        </v-container>
    </v-form>
</template>
```

I want to display content on the new line only if the condition is true.

I hope that make sense. Any help would be much valued ^^

Comment: Use conditional rendering <pre v-if="condtion true" class="CodeBackground">

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that's not what I want. I want to show blank character inside code based on a condition

Comment: You can use else statement I guess, <pre v-if="condtion true" class="CodeBackground"><pre v-else class="somethingElse">

Comment: Considering that you're dealing with blank lines. I think you could try commenting out the blank spaces (break lines) between your code, or remove them entirely (meaning that everything will be in a single line of code without any break lines).

Comment: @AlanTan Yeah, I think that makes sense. It makes my code dirty but I think I don't have any other option.